# What do the function signatures on php.net mean?

Tags: php

For example when I look at the documentation for [system](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) function:
it says:

> string system ( string $command [, int &$return_var ] )

What does this mean?
thanks

Comment: they're hints as to what types the arguments should be. `$command is a string, and $return_var is an integer`.

Comment: This format is quite common. But if you don't have a C/Java/.. background, here goes: 1. `string` the type that function returns, 2. name of the function, then `string` type of the argument & name of the argument. If the argument is in `[` and `]` it is optional. Names of the arguments are only important for the description which is beneath the signature

Comment: thanks, does the `&` have a meaning?

Comment: Yes, `&` has a meaning.... [pass by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for the parts of:

```
string system ( string $command [ , int & $return_var ]  )
1      2      3 4      5        6 7 8   9 10          11 12
```

in order:

1. string - the return type
2. system - the command name
3. ( - the beginning of the arguments to the function
4. string - the first argument's type
5. $command - the first argument's name (this is just a hint, it doesn't affect how you call the function)
6. [ - beginning of optional arguments
7. , - this is to show that you separate arguments with a comma
8. int - the type of the first optional argument
9. & - indicates that the first optional argument will be passed by reference (the function can modify the passed variable **)
10. $return_var - the name of the first optional argument
11. ] - end of the optional arguments
12. ) - end of the arguments to the function

It is hinting as to what might be required to call the function. So syntactically, the following are OK:

```
$return_type = 1;
system("String!", $return_type);
//$return_type could have changed

system("String!", $return_type);

system("String!");
```

But the following are not:

```
system();

system($var_that_wont_cast_to_string);
```

** PHP docs on pass by reference: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Comment: awesome answer, thanks. 1 thing, item 9. do you mean ... will be passed by reference (and *outer* scope variable can be modified in the called function) ? thanks

Comment: edited answer -- it made sense in my head :p. I think best not to go into meaning of pass by reference here, so just borrowing PHP's extensive treatment instead.

Answer (score 1):

Means that the function name is system(), and those are the parameters and types of this function.

in this case, string $command is mandatory (and you need to pass an valid String value). When you have brackets, like in (&$return_var) is an optional parameter (& means the variable will be passed as reference, so the return value will be on the variable you pass to the function).

Answer (score 1):

See here for the description given within php.net itself:

http://php.net/manual/en/about.prototypes.php

Answer (score -2):

The listing of `string` or `int` are telling you what types of value it expects.  It expects `system` to be of type `string`, an so on.  If you put an `int` for `system`, you will get an error

Comment: `string system` is the return type and the function name. How would you "put and int" for the return value? Also, php is loosely typed so in most places, an implicit conversion will happen if you pass in the wrong type. The types are really telling you how it will be treated in the function.